# Retrieving a text message from php file in android

Tags: php, android

Following is the code snippet I have integrated to upload an image to WAMP server and get the response from server.

```
private void uploadImage() {
        String name = "image";
        String path = p;
        try {
            String uploadid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadid, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image")
                    .addParameter("name", name)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(second.this, " Before the SHOW msg" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try{
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    Toast.makeText(second.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CharSequence cs = s;
                    inf.setText(cs);
                }
            };

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The code inside onResponse method is not working as the toast message inside it is not getting displayed  in mobile. I'm expecting the echo message inside php to be assigned to string 's' in onResponse and in turn the message goes on the EditText(inf).

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Have you checked Logcat? If you say that `onResponse` is not called, are you getting an exception instead?